# Old jQuery syntax error since upgrading to newer library

Tags: jquery

Is this old piece of jQuery calling it's parent function each time an element gains blur?

This code worked fine with an older version of jQuery (v1.4.1), but since upgrading the line in bold throws an error in IE dev tools: 'Function expected'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setoptionalcheckboxes();
    setprivatefueldropdowns();

    $("input[onblur]").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("onblur")(); //ERROR THROWN HERE
    });

    initcalculatevehiclebenefits();    
    inittaxablecalculations();
    initcalculatevehicletaxable();
    initsetdecimalpoint();
    calculatetotal();
    checkvehicledeletebutton();

    $(".gross, .pbe, .vehicle-cc").blur();
});
```

Comment: $(this).blur() have you tried this one ?

Comment: You misunderstood the question - onblur there should be a function called, and I think it's a call to the parent. see ending ()

Comment: yes i still unable to understand your question, what you want to do. don't you want to call function that  is binded to input's onblur attribute ?

Comment: I do indeed, but what do the '()' currently call at the end of the line?

Comment: $(this).attr("onblur") return string, what ()  is doing next to it is mystery for me, it is making it as invalid

Comment: Yet perfectly valid when using an older jquery library

Comment: The code is valid in jQuery 1.4.1

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
$("input[onblur]").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("onblur")(); //ERROR THROWN HERE
    });
```

To this

```
 $("input[onblur]").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("onblur");
    });
```

Comment: What difference are you expecting this to have?

Comment: this is the standard syntax for .attr()

Comment: That's right, but it doesn't actually *do* anything. From the look of OPs code he's trying to call the function defined in the `onblur` attribute.

Comment: You misunderstood the question - onblur there should be a function called, and I *think* it's a call to the parent. see ending ()